# Add remove fragment dynamically in FragmentPagerAdapter causes null exception

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tablayout

I have an application where I have several fragments, some of these need to be added or removed dynamically.  So I start with 2 fragments.  After login, I remove 1 fragment and add 2 or 3 more.  And depending on other actions then this can vary during the life of the app.

Each fragment appears in a tab with a title.

My main activity layout looks like this;

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.kaisersmith.whereami.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am using a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and I can add fragments OK.  But when I remove them it seems to work OK but isn't.  The Tab titles are correct, but when I try to move to another tab then I get an exception.  The exception is;

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:876)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1175)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:608)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2008)
    at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1025)
```

Extracts from my Page Viewer

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
...
 public void addFragment(Fragment frag, String title)
    {
        if (!this.fragments.contains(frag))
        {
            this.fragments.add(frag);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
...
public void removeFragment(String title)
    {
        Fragment frag = findFragmentByTitle(title);

        if (frag != null)
        {
            this.fragments.remove(frag);

            //String tag = this.fragments.get(loc).getTag();
            //Fragment fragment = this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            if(frag != null)
                this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
        }
    }
```

It is being called from my mainactivity as such;

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(new LoginFragment(),"Sign in");
mSectionsPagerAdapter.removeFragment("Logout");
mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I have looked at many examples on the internet, but most are too basic and have fixed Fragments that do not change.  Or the examples how to add/remove Fragments don't work in other ways.

Hiding the fragments & tabs would be another option but as far as I can tell it is not possible to hide them in a Toolbar

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I meet a same expection,but my code is different.

```
        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return fragments[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }
    });
```

The `fragments` is a Fragment array.
When I debug,I found that the `fragment.mActivity` on the `FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem()` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing like this:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private FragmentManager mManager;
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.mManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        mManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentList.get(position)).commit();
        mFragmentList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this is really any fundamentally different from my code.   But I tried it anyway and get the same null pointer exception

Comment: use 

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

after notifying adapter, that's how i was doing it.

Answer (score 0):

use replace method in FragmentTransaction  to add & remove

```
private void transactFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    }
```

use i recommenced to user framelayout as view container to add & replace fragments.

Comment: No, this hasn't worked, I get the same exception.  Only this time I can still see the tab of the fragment I tried to remove.